# Не работает передача аргументов через "..."

Tags: c++

Дано: число N и последовательность a1, a2, … aN
Создать шаблон класса, порождающий динамические одномерные массивы с элементами различных типов (вещественные, целочисленные, символьные и т.д.). Тип данных и результат являются параметрами по отношению к классу, программа должна иметь методы инициализации, конструктор, деструктор.

```
template < int size, typename type > class A {

  type *a;

  public:

  A() {

  a = new type[size];

  }

  ~A() {

    delete[] a;

  }

  void init(type t...) {

   // пока просто хочу вывести эл-ты 

   type *p_t = &t;

   for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
     std::cout << *(p_t + i) << " ";


  }

 // перенести в *a проблем нет
 // проблемы происходят при чтении *(p_t + i)


};
```

при int всё норм, а при float или double - первый элемент норм , а остальные мусор.

компилятор GNU GCC

по заданию мне нельзя создавать массив типа type вне класса
можно, конечно, создать ф-цию типа add(int index, type t), но в задание этого (методы инициализации) кажется нельзя делать.

Comment: прости за мою тупость. В смысле "не валидный" ?

Comment: у меня работает

Comment: template<int size_element, typename type> class MyArray {

  type *head;

  public:

  MyArray(){

    head = new type[size_element];

    for(int i = 0; i < size_element; i++)
      head[i] = 0;
  }

  ~MyArray() {

    delete[] head;

  }

  void init(type element, ...) {

    type *p = &element;

    for(int i = 0; i < size_element; i++)
     std::cout << *(p + i) << " ";


  }

  void print() {

    //element_print();

  }
};

Comment: если про void init(type t...) и void init(type t, ...) то у меня работает так и так.

Answer (score 3):

Три точки (эллипсис) в сигнатуре функции можно использовать только через макросы из `<cstdarg>` (`va_list` и т.п.).

Нельзя написать `void init(type t, ...)` и думать что `(&t + 1)` выдаст адрес второго аргумента. Такая операция приводит к неопределенному поведению (UB).

Правильно - это

```
void init(type t, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, t);
    std::cout << t << ' '; // первый параметр
    for (int i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
        std::cout << va_arg(args, type) << ' '; // остальные
    }
    va_end(args);
}
```

Однако использование `...` не рекомендуется. Для данного случая надо использовать конструктор, принимающий `std::initializer_list<T>`.

Comment: спасибо,я подозревал что адреса в type ... даются не подряд ,  cheat engine мне это подтвердил. <cstdarg> у меня не работает не с флагам, не без них, а std::initializer_list<T> мне понравился еще раз спасибо.

Comment: @Abyx не только 'Три точки (эллипсис) в сигнатуре функции можно использовать только через макросы' . Еще ж 'c++ template parameter pack'

Comment: @Abyx ах, да точно. Там же три точки в другой раскладке клавиатуры .... .

Comment: Откуда инфа про UB? Я ещё могу понять про отсутствие переносимости, но чтоб UB.

Comment: @alexolut, отсутсвие переносимости это и есть UB. Правда, иногда, первое слово тут будет unspecified, но это не тот случай.

Comment: @Abyx ошибаетесь, т.к. примерно в такой код и разворачивается макрос `va_arg` на `vc++` для `x86`.

Comment: @Abyx С одной стороны согласен. При этом получается довольно странная штука: Стандарт говорит: используй макрос `va_arg` и будет всё хорошо. А если взять тот же самый развернутый макрос, то уже получаем UB. Даже если код после препроцессора получается идентичный. Не получается это уложить у себя в голове.